# Drag and swap custom views in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, tabwidget

1) I have a tab widget which has 5 tabs [each tab showing an image and text].
2) 5th tab is for 'More' option. When the user selects this tab a sliding drawer will be opened which has grid of custom views [content same as each tab has, an image and text under it].
3) Now, user can click on any view from the sliding drawer and then drag it and swap with any of the tabs.